# Open a new terminal and ssh to a remote machine

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I want to open a new terminal and ssh to a remote machine in the opened terminal, and this terminal has to be kept open so that it can be used later to work on.

I tried the command : `gnome-terminal -x ssh user@IPaddress`. But I am unable to give any commands in the  newly opened terminal.

Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong and correct me?

Thanks in advance,
Saeya

Comment: gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e 'ssh -X root@$IP "tail -f /home/log/alog.log"'

Comment: What I do in `gnome-terminal` is to create profiles for all the remote machines I use frequently setting the Profile default command to `ssh -X user@my.host.com`. I also use different color schemas for every remote system so it becomes evident in which system I am.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested exactly the code you wrote (inserting a valid user and ip, of course) and it worked fine, so I can't see where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if your session is timing out once it is established you can add the ServerAliveInterval option to the command line

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -l user server'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked successfully : `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NOCLOSEPROFILE -e "ssh -X $user@$IPaddress"`.

Comment: Is it possible to execute a command in foreground in this newly opened  terminal from the terminal (in localhost) in which gnome-terminal was executed to open the new terminal?